# Display losing settings after it's powered down

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I've got this weird problem. I run ubuntu 20.04 on a custom built PC with Core i7-9700 (with inbuilt Intel graphics) and with Samsung CRG9 screen that I'm currently trying to run in PBP mode. I ran it before as one screen with 5120x1440 resolution, and after putting the correct settings into xrandr using a custom /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d entry I made it work in that resolution over a DP cable at 60hz. It worked everywhere after initial logon screen - after the PC booted the resolution would be lower till I logged on.

For productivity / convenience I decided to try running the screen in PBP mode split into two QHD (2560x1440) screens using one DP and one HDMI cable. And it kinda works until the screen is powered down because the PC has been idle, after which it comes back skewed up - the screens are replaced and one of them is in some weird resolution that changes back to QHD immediately when I try to open display settings window. Below is what I get from xrandr when everything is ok:

```
creen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1190mm x 340mm
   2560x1440     99.95 +  59.95* 
   2560x1080    100.00    60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080    100.00    60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1190mm x 340mm
   2560x1440     59.95* 
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080    100.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

This is what xrandr returns when I power the screen back on from idle or switched off:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6400 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected 2560x1440+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1190mm x 340mm
   2560x1440     99.95*+  59.95  
   2560x1080    100.00    60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080    100.00    60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 connected primary 3840x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1190mm x 340mm
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080    100.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
  3840x1080 (0x5a3) 266.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3840 start 3888 end 3920 total 4000 skew    0 clock  66.62KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1093 total 1111           clock  59.97Hz
```

But immediately upon running xranrd, or starting the display settings applet, everything comes back to normal This is really annoying because among other things I'm doing I'm running a VM with my work on it and this seems to also impact the way it displays, only it's more complicated to get the screen back to usable condition if both screens were showing the VM at the time the monitor was powered down.

Any ideas on why this is happening? I'm beginning to suspect the screen's firmware cause the PBP mode has always been a bit problematic, even on Windows. But maybe there's a way I can force xrandr to use certain settings for both DP and HDMI connections at all times?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while and for some time I've given up trying. I reverted to using a single cable but then the screen isn't as good for productivity as can be. The answer to the problem is very simple: Wayland.

I enabled the choice between X11 and Wayland in gdm3 config, and when I opted for the latter the problem went away after setting the resolutions explicitly once.

Comment: Can you provide more details for those of us who aren't familiar with what Wayland (or possibly `gdm3`) are?